# Consolidate different alternative names of countries, under the official name

Tags: python-3.x

I'm searching for a list or python packages, to help me unify under one name different names of countries.

For example:

```
USA, SUA, United States, Unites States of America
Germany, Federal Republic of Germany, Deutschland, Duitsland
```

I want to consolidate them under the official name, and allocate them iso standard.

Comment: On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_country_names) you can find a list with a lot of alternative names. I think there is no module or database including ALL different names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package, country_converter, can do it: https://github.com/konstantinstadler/country_converter

As shown in their documentation,

```
import country_converter as coco
some_names = ['United Rep. of Tanzania', 'DE', 'Cape Verde', '788', 'Burma', 'COG',
              'Iran (Islamic Republic of)', 'Korea, Republic of',
              "Dem. People's Rep. of Korea"]
standard_names = coco.convert(names=some_names, to='name_short')
print(standard_names)
```

Should give

```
 ['Tanzania', 'Germany', 'Cabo Verde', 'Tunisia', 'Myanmar', 'Congo Republic', 'Iran', 'South Korea', 'North Korea']
```

You can also specify the format you want the country names to be printed, by changing the `to='name_short'` to `to='ISO2'`

Answer (score 1):

There is a well-documented and a pretty powerful library to do this and similar things in the project:

https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/

It covers not only short / official / unofficial names for countries, but also works properly with different Unicode subtleties:

> There’s also a “fuzzy” search to help people discover “proper” countries for names that might only actually be subdivisions. The fuzziness also includes normalizing unicode accents. There’s also a bit of prioritization included to prefer matches on country names before subdivision names and have countries with more matches be listed before ones with fewer matches:

```
pycountry.countries.search_fuzzy('England')
[Country(alpha_2='GB', alpha_3='GBR', name='United Kingdom', numeric='826', official_name='United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland')]
```